# Алгоритм поиска подстроки в массиве строк (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Необходимо реализовать алгоритм проверяющий наличие подстроки в массиве строк и возвращающая номера элементов массива, в которых встретилась указанная строка.

Т.е. допустим дан массив:
let arr = ['aad','asad','adsd'];
let sub = ['ad'];
В результате выполнения функции необходимо получить 0, 1.

Сложность в том, что по условию задачи нельзя пользоваться стандартными функциями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без встроенных функций:

```js
let arr = ['a@d', 'add', 'aadd', 'asad', 'test', 'adsd', 55555];
let str = 'ad';

/*****/

let indexList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if ( match(arr[i], str) ) { // совпало - true, не совпало - false
    indexList[indexList.length] = i;
  }
}

console.log(indexList); // Должно вывести [1, 2, 3, 5]

/*****/

function match(str, sub) {
  str = "" + str;
  sub = "" + sub;
  if (sub.length > str.length) {
    return false;
  } // Субстрока больше строки - сразу несовпадение.

  let interval = str.length - sub.length + 1;
  // строка из 3-х букв, субстрока из 2-х, значит нужно 2 проверки на полное совпадение
  for (let i = 0; i < interval; i++) {
    let match = 0; 
    for (let u = 0; u < sub.length; u++) {
      if( str[i+u] !== sub[u] ){ // По очереди сравниваются все буквы.
        break;
      } else {
        match++;
      }
    }
    if( match === sub.length ){ return true; }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант со встроенными функциями, на случай, если у кого-то будет аналогичная задача, но без искусственных ограничений. :)

```js
let arr = ['aad', 'abcd', 'adsd', 'da'];
let str = 'ad';

let result = arr.map((item, i) => item.indexOf(str) >= 0 ? i : -1).filter(item => item >= 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

В массив сохранять думаю удобнее всего, его уже можно обработать как надо.

```
let arr = ['ad','asad','adsd', 'ad']; 
let sub = ['ad'];
let res = [];
arr.forEach(function(elem) {
  if(elem == sub[0]) {
  res += '1';
  } else {
  res += '0';
  }
});
alert(res);
```

Мы просто сравниваем 0 элемент массива с сравниваемым массивом. 
Также можно в sub добавить несколько элементов, но для этого нужно дописать еще один if